# python pyinstaller UnicodeDecodeError cp949

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I get unicodedecodeerror when I try to install pyinstaller.

The error message reades:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 208687: illegal multibyte sequence

When I google this error, it looks like an error with codec to read the file.

Tried some of the solutions found online but didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code have function to print some data with the codec which the window shell does not support display. Remove them and try again(I cannot comment because not enough rep so i wrote here)